# Is there is an external trigger with AF-ON and Light Metering button?

Tags: triggers, external

I use a D7100 body with some lightweight lenses (Nikkor 50mm and Nikkor 55-300mm) with the back button as AF-ON, with the trigger in first press in light measurement mode and the trigger in second press for capture. Nothing fancy.

Recently I bought a Sigma 60-600mm and I want to use it by freehand (with both hands on the lens) so I also bought a [small external trigger](https://www.amazon.fr/CamRepublic-T%C3%A9l%C3%A9commande-D%C3%A9clencheur-distance-Compatible/dp/B073R5K6XX/) that I attached to the arcaswiss/tripod attach system.

It's working perfectly, I can lift the lens and the camera body without any problem, and I can zoom in and zoom out very easily.

The only problem is that I can't make the light measurement without pressing a button on the camera body because my both hands are on the lens.

So I was wondering if an external trigger support the feature of AF-ON, light measurement and trigger of course. If not, is it possible to Do It Myself by using the GPS port where the actual external trigger is connected ?

Comment: I don't know how the Nikon camera works, but my Canon remote will do the half-press, and the one you are pointing to seems to do so too. Otherwise there are just three wires, contact between one wire and common  is exposure/focus and contact between third wire and common is trigger.

Answer (score 1):

AF-ON disables the half press focussing in some Nikon cameras - though some are switchable, for AF-ON/shutter release or both interchangeably -  but I know of no way to remote the actual back button itself, only to restore the function to the shutter release & use a regular wired remote with half-press.

Presumably remoting to your phone etc would be even more ungainly.

What puzzles me slightly [though I don't know the D7100 specifically] is why it won't meter light without a button being held. My D5500 is always metering.